# How to read a CSV without the first column

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am trying to read a simple CSV file like below, and put its contents in a 2D array:

```
"","x","y","sim1","sim2","sim3","sim4","sim5","sim6","sim7","sim8","sim9","sim10","sim11","sim12"
"1",181180,333740,5.56588745117188,6.29487752914429,7.4835410118103,5.75873327255249,6.62183284759521,5.81478500366211,4.85671949386597,5.90418815612793,6.32611751556396,6.99649047851562,6.52076387405396,5.68944215774536
"2",181140,333700,6.36264753341675,6.5217604637146,6.16843748092651,5.55328798294067,7.00429201126099,6.43625402450562,6.17744159698486,6.72836923599243,6.38574266433716,6.81451606750488,6.68060827255249,6.14339065551758
"3",181180,333700,6.16541910171509,6.44704437255859,7.51744651794434,5.46270132064819,6.8890323638916,6.46842670440674,6.07698059082031,6.2140531539917,6.43774271011353,6.21923875808716,6.43355655670166,5.90692138671875
```

To do this, I use this:

```
data = np.loadtxt("Data/sim.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
```

But I always got this message:

```
"ValueError: could not convert string to float: "1"
```

I thought the problem was with the first column of each row. So, I tried to read it without the first column, but I couldn't find out how.

So, how could I ignore the first column? Is there a way to read this file with the first column?

Comment: You can specify which columns to read with `usecols`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can specify a converter for any column.

```
converters = {0: lambda s: float(s.strip('"')}
data = np.loadtxt("Data/sim.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, converters=converters)
```

Or, you can specify which columns to use, something like:

```
data = np.loadtxt("Data/sim.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,15))
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

---

One way you can skip the first column, without knowing the number of columns, is to read the number of columns from the csv manually. It's easy enough, although you may need to tweak this on occasion to account for formatting inconsistencies*.

```
with open("Data/sim.csv") as f:
    ncols = len(f.readline().split(','))

data = np.loadtxt("Data/sim.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,ncols+1))
```

**If there are blank lines at the top, you'll need to skip them. If there may be commas in the field headers, you should count columns using the first data line instead. So, if you have specific problems, I can add some details to make the code more robust.*

Comment: I was writing up the `converters` approach myself, but wouldn't the OP need something like `float(s.strip('"'))`?

Comment: Yeah, I though about the second solution. But not necessarily I will know the cols range. There is a way to say "use every column excepted the first one"?

Comment: It would be nice if there were a `dontusecols`, or if `usecols` could take a slice object instead of just an iterable (so you could just `usecols=slice(1, None)`, and also things like `usecols=slice(-1)` to skip the last row, etc.).

Comment: @abarnert Agreed. Or if you could set the default converter for every column to give `nan` instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 18):

You could use pandas and read it as a DataFrame object. If you know the column  that you do not want, just add a `.drop` to the loading line:

```
a = pandas.read_csv("Data/sim.csv",sep=",")
a = a.drop(a.columns[0], axis=1)
```

The first row will be read as a header, but you can add a skiprows=1 in the read_csv parameter.
Pandas DataFrames are numpy arrays, so, converting columns or matrices to numpy arrays is pretty straightforward.

Comment: you cannot use drop part when you first reading it. the above method will work only if you have already read the csv file in the variable 'a'.

Answer (score 6):

```py
import pandas

pandas_data = pandas.read_csv('filename', sep=",", header=0,index_col=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("Data/sim.csv",sep=",").iloc[:,1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

jmilloy and Deninhos's answers are both good. If OP specifically wants to read in an NumPy array (as opposed to pandas dataframe), another simplistic alternative is to delete the index column after reading it in. This works when you know the index column is always the first, but number of features (columns) are flexible.

```
data = np.loadtxt("Data/sim.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
data = np.delete(data, 0, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying reading csv file using csv library

```
import csv

def someFunc(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    i = 0
    header = True
    for row in reader:
        if header:
            header = False
            continue

        out[i] = [row[j] for j in range(len(columns))]
        i += 1
return out
```

out will have the 2D array.

Comment: The OP wants to build a numpy array, not a list of lists. (And building a list of lists just to build a numpy array will be somewhat slower and use a lot more memory… which is one of the main reasons people use numpy in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in csvreader:
        data.append(float(row[1]))
```

Answer (score -2):

Read the `csv` file like this.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=range(1, len(df.columns)))
```

Comment: How can `df.columns` be used if `df` hasn't yet been formed? It should throw an error.